# Can you increase Deceive's Critical Damage (Shaco)?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am interested in playing Shaco but have a fundamental question.

Does the critical damage from Shaco's Deceive ability benefit from Infinity Edge or +Crit Damage Runes?

The reason I ask is his ability is phrased thusly:

> Deceive - Shaco stealths himself instantly and teleports to target location. His next attack is guaranteed to critically strike.
>   Shaco instantly stealths for 3.5 seconds, and teleports to target nearby location. If he attacks while stealthed, the attack is guaranteed to crit for 40/60/80/100/120% bonus physical damage.

It seems counter intuitive to have the damage be called both critical and bonus damage and increase as the ability is leveled up.

I pose the following scenario:
Shaco with level 5 Deceive and Infinity Edge. We will assume he is doing a total of 100 damage to make the analysis easy. On attack after using Deceive will The attack deal 220 Damage (100 base + 120 from deceive) OR will the attack deal 270 damage (100 base + 120 from Deceive + 50 from Infinity Edge). If neither of the above scenarios are correct please enlighten me as I may be misunderstanding the interaction Infinity Edge has with base attacks compared to base attacks modified by abilities.

Edit: The following link may be helpful but they didn't really clarify as there may be a discrepancy between the European and US regions. [Shaco, Deceive and Crit Damage Runes (EU)](http://eu.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=12391)

Comment: I'm curious about the numbers in that scenario, but this comes from having never played Shaco. Does this mean that until skill level 4, Deceive does *less* damage on its "guaranteed critical" than an actual critical hit? I guess that considering 120% bonus on top of a normal critical would indeed be overkill for a basic skill, but I want to confirm that this is indeed how it behaves.

Comment: @Grace I think that the tool tip for the ability is just worded poorly. I have played Shaco extensively in the past few days and the "crit" following Deceive (at low levels of Deceive) behaves more like bonus damage applied to the attack based on his attack damage. Once you break the threshold (at levels 4-5) it starts to behave more like a normal Critical Hit. It seems the designers want Deceive to do bonus damage based on your attack damage but also have the flavor of an automatic critical strike (while not making the ability over powered at low levels).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is straight from the LOL wiki:

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shaco_the_Demon_Jester/Strategy

*The bonus critical strike damage from Infinity Edge will apply on critical hits from Deceive, in addition to the bonus magic damage the ability gives.*

So to answer your question: Yes Deceive benefits from Infinity Edge. It stands to reason that it will also benefit from Crit Dmg Runes. With that said, the following has been taken from League Craft forum posts: 
http://forum.leaguecraft.com/index.php?/topic/6388-shaco-deceive-crit-dmg-runes/

*Not sure about the math or the mechanics behind it, but I just tested Deceive at level 1 on a Master Yi at level 1 in a practice game, once with a full page of Crit Damage runes and one with some other random page that wouldn't affect the damage. All other factors were kept the same both times.
Results:
Without Crit Damage runes: 64 from the front, 80 from the back
With: 85 from the front, 100 from the back*

Of course, that was in June 2010...

Comment: " ...in addition to the bonus magic damage the ability gives." I have damage dealt text turned on and unless I have Malady or Madred's I only see 1 number and the "crit" text come up. So where does the bonus "magic" damage come from?

Comment: It will be included in that number. If you crit enough, you will find that the number is occasionally different...

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that this is not true anymore.

Now Deceive is only deals bonus damage, which are not critical anymore.

Critical hit can still happen in the normal way though.

Comment: Can you provide some source information? It's very likely the game mechanics have changed and you're right, but we don't necessarily know that for sure without some proof.

Comment: Well If I digged a bit more into it.

If I understood correctly, the bonus damage benefits from the critical bonus damage, but only the bonus damage.

On a normal critical hit, both base damage AND bonus damage benefits from the critical multiplier.

In that sense it's not really a critical, but the bonus apply to the spell. So the previous answser is correct indeed.